# Can't get data back to the web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple html form for Project Euler #1 (compute sum of numbers from 0 to 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5) that lets users input a number rather than calculating from 0 to 1000. I think what I have is close, but I'm not able to get any values to return on the web page.

```
<body>
    <form action="" id="numform" onsubmit="return false">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Lets do Math!</legend>
            <label>Enter a number</label>
            <input type="text" name="num" id="num">
            <button onclick="add">Calculate</button>
            <div id="totalSum"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>

function addThreeAndFive() {

    var theForm = document.forms["numform"];
    var num = theForm.elements["num"]
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('totalSum').innerHTML = "The sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 are " + sum;
}
```

Comment: also, `fieldset` is spelled incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <button onclick="addThreeAndFive()">Calculate</button>
```

Add a call to the function on button click

Also change num to var `num = theForm.elements["num"].value`

Comment: Also, remove the innerHTML assignment from the for loop.

Comment: After calling the function and removing innerHTML from the for loops it started displaying the message, but the value of sum always returns zero form some reason.

Comment: Awesome! It's displaying the data now. Thanks!